# Sources for long-term NDVI datasets with coverage to west Asia?

Tags: data, ndvi, climate

I'm in need for long-term NDVI dataset for my research in bio-climatology, looks like GLCF GIMMS are no longer available online, any suggestions/workarounds to get the data.

Answer (score 1):

Clark Labs has global NDVI archives spanning 1981-2000 (0.1 Degree AVHRR) and 2000-2009 (0.05 Degree MODIS) in IDRISI format:
http://www.clarklabs.org/products/global-gis-image-processing-data.cfm

Unfortunately, these are not free ($30 each), and only one can be downloaded (the other is provided on DVD). Order page here: 
http://clarklabs.org/buy/buy-online.cfm?method=main.chooseAddons

It may also be worth asking GLCF when/if GIMMS data will be made available again.

Comment: Thanks toms, I have emailed GLCF where they said they have no time schedule for the data release since it's being assembled.